# Solr Query to Spring Data Solr Query Expression (Negation)

Tags: java, spring, solr

This is my solr Query, which works well from the Solr interface , But I am not able to run the same through Spring-Data Solr . The negation or NOT doesn't seem to happen right.

`NOT( blocked:IN OR ( blocked:WW AND NOT( allowed : IN ) ) )`

Here's what I am writing in my Java Code.

`criteria =(new Criteria("blocked").contains(value).or(new Criteria("blocked").contains(value).and(new Criteria("allowed").contains(value).not())).notOperator());`

But this seems not to be working, I also tried negating the entire query to change the `NOT` and `OR` to `AND` as an alternative but it also doesn't seem to work.

Is there any other way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the criteria expression is identical to the example you had pasted.

The brace before the notOperator needs to be moved.

criteria =(new Criteria("blocked").contains(value).
                            or(new Criteria("blocked").contains(value).and(
                    new Criteria("allowed").contains(value).not()))**)**.notOperator();

You might actually not try to create the anonymous criteria objects - in order to make it readable.  This is one of those cases where you'd pick multiple lines of code over single line of code.

Comment: You can check solr logs to see which query is generated by the Criteria.  That may be helpful in restructuring that expression.